# Java - Issue with reading file

Tags: java, io

I have this function:

```
public static int checkRank(String lineToCompare){
    int rank = 0;
    try{
        // Open the file that is the first 
        // command line parameter
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("ranks.txt");

        // Get the object of DataInputStream
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

        String strLine;
        //Read File Line By Line
        System.out.println("SPOT 0");
        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
            //Compare the line with the line to compare (string)
            System.out.println("SPOT 1");
            if(strLine.trim().equals(lineToCompare)) {
                //I found it!  Read the next line...
                final String lineAfter = br.readLine();
                rank = Integer.parseInt(lineAfter);  
                System.out.println("SPOT 2");
            }else{
                rank = 0;
                System.out.println("SPOT 3");
            }
        }

        //Close the input stream
        in.close();
    }catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }

    System.out.println("Username: " + lineToCompare + " | Rank: " + rank);
    return rank;
}
```

My `ranks.txt` file is as follows:

```
test1
2
test2
1
```

The console outputs (the "SPOT"s were just used for debugging):

```
[Commands] SPOT 0
[Commands] SPOT 1
[Commands] SPOT 2
[Commands] SPOT 1
[Commands] SPOT 3
[Commands] SPOT 1
[Commands] SPOT 3
[Commands] Username: test1 | Rank: 0
```

As you can see, if it were working correctly it would say test1 has a rank of 2. Can someone help me identify the problem?

Comment: What is `lineToCompare`?

Comment: @Jeffrey, lineToCompare = test1 (as it shows in the console's output).

Comment: Try adding a break; after printing SPOT2. You set the rank to 0 after you read "test2" and then again when you read "1".

Comment: @DannyF247 Aha! The code box has a scroll bar. Sorry about that

Comment: @ppalasek Thanks that fixed it!! If you want to leave that as an answer so I can accept it and get you rep, I'd be more than happy to :)

Comment: The `DataInputStream` is adding no value here. Remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a break; statement after the line where you print out "SPOT 2" to end the while loop.

Without the break you set the rank to 0 when you read the line "test2" and then again when you read the line "1" (the while loop continues until the end of file).

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting `rank` with `0` in the last loop iteration.

Break out of the loop using `break;` when you get a hit.